# JQuery: DOM traversal testing

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a function to change thumbnail selection in JQuery. It was working fine when I had more-specific selectors but I'm trying to do it class-based to prevent repeating myself.

It presently looks like this:

```
function changeImage(thisElement) {
    var src = $(thisElement + ' option:selected').val();
    console.log('thisElement = ' + src);
    $(thisElement).parent().parent().parent().next('.selector_thumbnails img').css('display', 'none');
    $(thisElement).parent().parent().parent().next('.selector_thumbnails img#' + src).css('display', 'block');
  }
  $('.thumbnail_selector').change(function() { changeImage('.thumbnail_selector'); });
  if ($('.thumbnail_selector').length) { changeImage('.thumbnail_selector'); }
```

I get the log output like so:

```
thisElement = 141
```

I'm almost certain the DOM-traversal is correct, but I've no way to test it without trial-and-error which is pretty frustrating. Is there a better way to test JQuery functions like this?

The working version looks like this:

```
$('#document_cover_id').change(function() {
    var src = $(this).val();
    $('#thumbcover img').css('display', 'none');
    $('#cover_thumb'+src).css('display', 'block');
});
```

But I don't want to use the IDs. The DOM looks like this:

[image: DOM example]

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

The IDs have changed since the working version.

**EDIT 2**

Added a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wpm2pst/5/) to show the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the `.thumbnail_selector` is not a sibling of the `.col-sm-9` but a sibgling to the `.form-group` (*in your current code*).

So the `.closest('.col-sm-9').next(..)` doesn't work.

Your whole script could be simplified to

```
function changeImage() {
    var self = $(this),
        src = this.value,
        thumbs = self.closest('.form-group').siblings('.selector_thumbnails');

   thumbs
       .find('img')
       .hide()
       .filter('#' + src)
       .show();
}

$('.thumbnail_selector')
    .change(changeImage)
    .trigger('change');
```

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/2wpm2pst/7/

Comment: Ah! Thank-you so much! That makes a lot of sense. I thought I was going crazy.

Answer (score 0):

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pmytmqou/
JQuery:

```
function changeImage(thisElement) {
var src = $(thisElement + ' option:selected').val();
console.log('thisElement = ' + src);
$('.selector_thumbnails > img').css('display', 'none');
$('#' + src).css('display', 'block');
}
$('.thumbnail_selector').change(function () {
    changeImage('.thumbnail_selector');
});
if ($('.thumbnail_selector').length) {
    changeImage('.thumbnail_selector');
}
```

An id selector should be unique in a page so you can just use the #id selector.

To answer your testing question JQuery has a unit test suite called QUnit. you can find more about it here: qunitjs.com/